# Handsontable Dropdown Filter

Tags: handsontable

I am having a bit of problem with Handsontable.
Is there a way to check if the small window for the dropdown Filter is opened?
For example, if someone clicks the head of the column you get a log in your console that the dropdown-filter is opened and if the settings for the filter are done you get another log "filter window closed"

[example of dropdown filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz8Q0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handsontable provides some hooks you can use in your case.

You can hook the dropdown menu opening with `beforeDropdownMenuShow` ([documentation](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.3.0/Hooks.html#event:beforeDropdownMenuShow)) and you can hook the event when filters are applied with `beforeFilter` ([documentation](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.3.0/Hooks.html#event:beforeFilter)).

I hope it helps you. If you want more details on how to use them please provide StackBlitz.